# How to pass arguments directly from json file to keyword in robot framework?

Tags: json, python-2.7, robotframework

I have a Json file like this.PFB the code:

```
"properties " : {
    "xyz" : {
        "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "password" : "abc@123",
        "phonenumber" : "1235",
    },
      "ABC" : {
        "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "password" : "abc@123",
        "phonenumber" : "1345",
    },
```

Keyword will be like :

```
Do operation for properties
  [Arguments]  ${username}  ${password}  ${phonenumber}
  Log  ${username}
  Log  ${password} 
  Log  ${phonenumber}
```

My questions are :

1) The json file contains so many things but i have to fetch only properties from the file.How i will take properties part from the entire json file and pass directly arguments like username , password , phonenumber into keyword mentioned above.

2) How to write keyword for this logic such that we change only json file for adding more properties like apart from xyz, abc we will add as many properties we want and it will automatically fetch and keyword give us the desired result for all properties whatever we are modifying in json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your question's summary is: a) how to read and parse a json file in Robotframework in this form, and b) pass each record's attributes to this keyword.

A file can be read from the file system with [`Get File`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20File).

One can read a json file with the python's `json` module, more specifically the `loads()` method - it takes a string, and returns a python object.

Your "json" sample is quite invalid json, so let's imagine that "properties" is somewhere (3 levels deep) inside the file.

```
${the file as string}=    Get File    c:\\the\\path\\to\\the\\file.json
${parsed}=    Evaluate    json.loads("""${the file as string}""")    json
${properties}=    Set Variable    ${parsed["top"]["child"]["properties"]}
```

And now the variable `properties` is a dictionary, with those two keys - "ABC" and "xyz"; you just iterate over it, and pass the subkeys of each of the sub-dictionaries to the keyword.

```
FOR    ${key}    IN    @{properties}
  ${sub dict}=    Get From Dictionary    ${properties}    ${key}
  Do operation for properties    ${sub dict}[username]    ${sub dict}[password]    ${sub dict}[phonenumber]
END
```

Comment: @Todor-Thanks for your reply!!! It really helped but when i ran i got this error:Dictionary '${sub dict}' has no key '"username"'. Why this error is coming ?

Comment: Because the sub-dictionary you are working with is not with the structure you expect. Inside the loop, just after the "Get From Dictionary" keyword, add a `Log    ${sub dict}` and you will see what is the actual one.

Comment: I ran the script & i got following output of Log ${sub dict}:                                               {u'username': u'abc@gmail.com', u'password': u'abc@123', u'phonenumber': u'1235'} . It seems the issue is coming due to u'. What's the way to remove u' so that it will detect key "username" ?

Comment: It's not the "u" symbol; looks like I've made a mistake in the answer, on dictionary access the key shouldn't be in quotes. Updated it, try with the newer version.